# Remote Domains are not opening with Phonegap 3.1.0

Tags: android, cordova

Really i have a serious problem with Phongap Build 3.1.0.

I added following code in config.xml(its under /myApp/platform/android/res/)

```
<access origin="http://google.com*" />
<content src="http://google.com" />
```

And when i open the APP its telling "`The connection to the server was unsuccessfull. (http://google.com)`"

Suppose if i open the URL with `inAppBrowser` its opening without any error.

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your config.xml under www

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />
```

Comment: I Tried this too... but no use... I hope in latest phonegap build(3.1.0) we cannot open remote website directly like previous Phonegap Builds(2.7.0).

Comment: Did you also remove <content src="`http://google.com`" /> I think that line is the problem. It should just point to your local file.

Comment: no... i tested in some other way. Ex: i gave permission to *.google.com and when i put http://google.com in <content src="" /> when i open the app on device its asking me where to open google.com in browser or Chrome or opera. :(

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem with 3.1 and found it's because 3.1 changed the whitelisting syntax, as documented here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Try this:

```
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```

Comment: I was update the Phonegap to 3.2 and everything works fine :D